# YouTube iframe wmode issue with no suggestions

Tags: iframe, wmode

I am using the `wmode="transparent"` for the `iframe` to accommodate for the dropdown menus on my site. I also want to use the `?rel=0` for the No Suggested videos at the end of my videos. What do I need to add to my `iframe` code to make this work?

Comment: What do you currently have?

Comment: <iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/IK2eNq1O098?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0"></iframe>